# UIButton wierdness: Unable to set title for a custom button type

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uibutton

I'm trying to set the title for a custom button that I've created programmatically. The button's image and the frame come up fine, but the title doesn't. I can't really think of anything wrong with this code, so any help is apreciated!

```
self.helpButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[self.helpButton setFrame:CGRectMake(113.0, 685.5, 73.0, 40.0)];
UIImage *helpImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"11_HelpCancel_Up.png"];
[self.helpButton setImage:helpImg 
               forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.helpButton setTitle:@"Help" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.helpButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
// [self.helpButton setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14.0]];
[self.view addSubview:self.helpButton];
```

Thanks, 
Teja.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use

```
[self.helpButton setBackgroundImage:helpImg forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

`- setImage:forState:` seems to override `- setTitle:forState:`

Answer (score 0):

Was having trouble with the button title showing up on my storyboard when I switched the type of button from system -> custom. The problem was the color of the text changed to white when I made the change so anyone having a similar issue, make sure to check the color of the button text.